# Работа с bzip2 - как заархивировать файл.

Tags: freebsd

Достоверно известно, что чтобы заархивировать файл bzip2 необходимо выполнить операцию :
*bzip2 filename*
Но, при етом затирается используемый файл.
Мне необходимо, чтобы во первых он не затирался, во вторых архив был создан в другой папке.
 Я пытался делать так:
*bzip2 -9 filename > ~user1/filename.bz2*
не выходит
Прошу помочь.
tar прошу не предлагать.

Comment: man bzip2 подсказывает ключ -k

     bzip2 -k filename

      -k --keep
              Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.

Answer (score 1):

bzip2 -c -9 filename > ~user1/filename.bz2

Comment: Не сохраняет время изменения файла